# How to override css containing '!important' using JavaScript under HTML input objects?

Tags: css, overriding, onmouseover, onmouseout

I actually work on a plugin for wordpress and I have problem to dynamically stylize a button form (**input[type="submit"]**), because some wordpress themes use the "**!important**" property.

I want to override that use JavaScript under HTML input objects, because i want to call some css value using php.

In the demo below I have volentary put the "**!important**" property in the css style to try to override it.

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/kqnakcxz/5/)

```css
input[type="submit"] {
    font-family: FontAwesome, 'Diplomata SC', "Helvetica Neue", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display:block;
    background-color: #333333!important;
    color: #FFFFFF!important;
    padding: 5px 11px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 15x;  
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14) inset;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #27ccc0!important;
  color: #FFFFFF!important;
}
```

```html
<input 
onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#6ce033'; this.style.color='#FFF'; return true;"
onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#40c200'; this.style.color='#FFF'; return true;"
type="submit">
```

```html
<?php
function add_button($id) {
 
 $stored_meta = get_post_meta($id);
 $btn_bg_color = esc_attr( $stored_meta['btn_bg_color'][0]);
 $btn_txt_color = esc_attr( $stored_meta['btn_txt_color'][0]);
 $hover_btn_bg_color = esc_attr( $stored_meta['hover_btn_bg_color'][0]);
 $hover_btn_txt_color = esc_attr( $stored_meta['hover_btn_txt_color'][0]);
 



echo '<input onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='."'".$btn_bg_color."'".'; this.style.color='."'".$btn_txt_color."'".'; return true;"
 onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='."'".$hover_btn_bg_color."'".'; this.style.color='."'".$hover_btn_txt_color."'".'; return true;" type="submit">'

?>
}
```

**Above, a concrete example of what I want to do. Changing the style depending the post id.**

Comment: I had already seen this post, but is not exactly that I want. I have updated my question by adding a concrete php example.

Comment: But there is no difference between JavaScript added by PHP, and "just" JavaScript. The answers in the other question work equally well. For instance, you can write `echo "<input onmouseover=\"this.style.setProperty('background-color', '{$btn_bg_color}', 'important'); this.style.setProperty('color', "{$btn_txt_color}', 'important'); return true;\"` etc

Comment: If that doesn't work, explain what goes wrong.

Comment: Its exactly what i did the first time, but the error is i had make two time the "setProperty()" in onmouseover"". 
The solustion is :
<input onmouseout="this.setAttribute('style', 'background-color:#ff5223 !important; color:#FFFFFF !important');" type="submit">. 
Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't seem to find which exactly in the previous answer would solve your problem, here's an example implementation.

```css
input[type="submit"] {
    font-family: FontAwesome, 'Diplomata SC', "Helvetica Neue", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display:block;
    background-color: pink!important;
    color: #FFFFFF!important;
    padding: 5px 11px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 15x;  
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14) inset;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: red!important;
  color: #FFFFFF!important;
}
```

```html
<input onmouseover="this.setAttribute('style','background: #6ce033 !important; color: #fff !important;');" onmouseout="this.setAttribute('style','background: #40c200 !important; color: #fff !important;');" type="submit">
```

There is a bug where the button is initially pink and doesn't change until you mouseover it. You can hack around this by adding a unique id to the input then creating a script right after the input to immediately change the style attribute of the input field.

```css
input[type="submit"] {
    font-family: FontAwesome, 'Diplomata SC', "Helvetica Neue", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display:block;
    background-color: pink!important;
    color: #FFFFFF!important;
    padding: 5px 11px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 15x;  
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14) inset;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: red!important;
  color: #FFFFFF!important;
}
```

```html
<input
  onmouseover="
    this.setAttribute('style',
      'background: #6ce033 !important; color: #fff !important;'
    );"
  onmouseout="
    this.setAttribute('style',
      'background: #40c200 !important; color: #fff !important;'
    );"
  type="submit"
  id="button_ID" />

<script>
  var button = document.getElementById("button_ID");
  button.setAttribute('style',
    'background: #40c200 !important; color: #fff !important;'
  );
</script>
```

Take note however that both of these solutions are pretty hacky. There are better ways to do things like this, but obviously that is out of this question's scope.

---

<strike>Can't you just [add a class to the input](https://jsfiddle.net/yk0xbkn2/)?</strike>

```
input[type="submit"].some-override-class {
    background: #40c200 !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}

input[type="submit"].some-override-class:hover {
    background: #6ce033 !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

The best way to override existing CSS is to further specify its importance using additional classes, IDs, or contexts.

Comment: I want to use JavaScript under HTML input objects, because I want to dynamicly generate a multiple button in the same page, and these button have the same class name, but they have deferent values in the proprety: background and color (on normal and hover state)

Comment: See the question posted as a duplicate. You will find your answers there :)

Comment: I had already seen the duplicate question, but is not exactly that I want.

Comment: Updated my answer.